# Creating Game invite code for Android game

Tags: android

I want to know the best approach to do the following.

Sharing game invite code:

An approach I think is creating a random code linked to the game id and store in db and fetch details from invitee's side.

Didn't see any info on this. Is this the best approach? Any other easier approaches? Main idea is a person can create many games and invite other players to play his/her games.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a random ID to invite every time, just create Invite code for each user during registration time. So each user has their Invite code.